# Error with QObject::connect(). Application Crashes. No build Error

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a calculator app to do simple calculations. It does not show any error in Build but crashes on Run -
The program has unexpectedly finished.Desktop_Qt_5_4_2_MinGW_32bit2-Debug\debug\calc.exe crashed

#### calculator.h

```
#ifndef CALCULATOR
#define CALCULATOR
#include <QWidget>
class calculator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    calculator ( QWidget *parent=0);
    int value=0;

private slots:
    void setValue(int);

};

#endif // CALCULATOR
```

#### calculator.cpp

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <calculator.h>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QGridLayout>

calculator::calculator(QWidget *parent)
{
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QPushButton *add = new QPushButton;
    add->setText("+");
    QPushButton *sub = new QPushButton;
    sub->setText("-");
    QPushButton *mul = new QPushButton;
    mul->setText("*");
    QPushButton *div = new QPushButton;
    div->setText("/");
    QPushButton *enter = new QPushButton;
    enter->setText("enter");
    QLineEdit *disp = new QLineEdit(parent);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    layout->addWidget(disp,0,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(add,1,0,0);
    layout->addWidget(sub,1,1,0);
    layout->addWidget(mul,1,2,0);
    layout->addWidget(div,1,3,0);
    layout->addWidget(enter,2,0,0);
    window->setLayout(layout);
    window->show();

    calculator field1, field2, result;
    connect(add,SIGNAL(clicked()),&field1,SLOT((calculator::setValue(disp->text().toInt()))));
    disp->clear();
    connect(enter,SIGNAL(clicked()),&field2,SLOT(calculator::setValue(disp->text().toInt())));
    result.value=field1.value+field2.value;
    disp->setText(QString::number(result.value));

 }

 void calculator::setValue(int val)
 {
    value=val;
 }
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <calculator.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    calculator cal;

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You are calling `calculator` constructor inside of `calculator` construstor wich leads to infinite recursion and memory overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You connect signal to the slot of object on the stack:

```
calculator field1, field2, result;
connect(add,SIGNAL(clicked()),&field1,SLOT((calculator::setValue(disp->text().toInt()))));
```

So when this slot is called object already destroyed.
Instead of creating new calculator object you should connect to the slot of this:

```
connect(add,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(setValue()));
```

Please pay attention that for signal without arguments you need to have slot without arguments. So for every widget you want to handle, if they have different behaviour, you need to create different slot.

Fix this for all connections.

Comment: `SLOT((calculator::setValue(disp->text().toInt())))` won't work.

Comment: @Amartel, right - thank you. Just made fast copy and missed wrong slot, will update answer